# How to create nested Schema with object, arrays and keys

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am currently trying to create a nested schema for a  MERN application(I  just started learning mongoose), I have a feeling the schema I created wasn't done correctly. I would like to validate this response :

```
quiz: [
    {
       question: "What is 4 X 4 ? ",
       answers: [
            { 
               type: "Smart",
               content: "16" 
            },
            {
               type: "Below_Average",
               content: "15"
            },
            { 
               type: "Clueless",
               content: "1" 
            }
        ]            
    },
   ]
```

//this is what I have done

```
const QuizSchema = new Schema({    
    question: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    answers: {
        type: Array
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    } 
});
```

what is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a nested array of objects like that:

```
const QuizSchema = new Schema({

    question: {
        type:String,
        default:''
    },
    answers: [{
        type: {
            type: String,
            default:''
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            default:''
        },
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I will implement it and return the outcome